# R: Error when installing package "gifski"

Tags: r, gganimate

I hope you're staying well. I am trying to install the gifski package so that I can run tmap_animation().

Here's the error message I see:

```
Installing package into ‘/nfs/cfs/home4/wmjl/wmjlwuh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/gifski_1.4.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 12729 bytes (12 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 12 KB

* installing *source* package ‘gifski’ ...
** package ‘gifski’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
./configure: line 5: cargo: command not found
------------------ RUST COMPILER NOT FOUND --------------------

Cargo was not found on the PATH. Please install cargo / rustc:

 - yum install cargo         (Fedora/CentOS)
 - apt-get install cargo     (Debian/Ubuntu)
 - brew install rust         (MacOS)

Alternatively install Rust from: <https://www.rust-lang.org>

---------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘gifski’
* removing ‘/nfs/cfs/home4/wmjl/wmjlwuh/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/gifski’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘gifski’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've tried following the instructions above (namely, installing rust on MacOS) without any success.

Can anyone provide any guidance on this issue?

Thank you so much,

Yaning

Answer (score 0):

Did you follow each step on this [website](https://www.rust-lang.org/tools/install) ??

You should probably also do the change in the PATH as said in the chapter:
**Configuring the PATH environment variable**

Can you provide more information of what you have done please ?

Comment: Hi, I did. I might have to configure the PATH environment variable though - I have just gotten the installation to work on the desktop version of RStudio that I'm using instead of the server that I previously used, so this is less of a concern now. Thank you so much!

Comment: You can validate my answer since everything is ok for you now ?